# How to remove one folder from C:\Windows\winsxs?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, winsxs

I've installed:
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)

and got the following folders:
x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91
x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4926_none_508ed732bcbc0e5a

I allready uninstalled the redistribute package but they continue overthere.

I want to remove them because I want to test my program without installing nothing (I've included those dll's when building it in another computer).

So, how can I remove those folders from C:\Windows\winsxs?

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Modifying the registry or filesystem directly is a bit dangerous, since there's a lot of extra configuration data associated with installed assemblies.

The fact that those files are still present doesn't do great harm (WinSxS is a *cache*), what's important is whether the system treats them as installed or not. I've blogged about how to accomplish this here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/talagrand/archive/2010/03/02/9973115.aspx

Comment: Wow, that's a useless blog post.  Short from a utility that does nothing, it is completely useless to the OP's task.  Why don't you give a *real* answer instead of spamming your blog and downvoting an answer that actually tries to help this victim.

Comment: With respect, I downvoted your answer because it advocates corrupting install state on the machine. Zapping those registry values would prevent other software using the CRT9 from installing or operating correctly (they don't actually contain install state, so other installers would not repair the damage).

Comment: The original question was "I want to test my program without installing nothing", implying a clean machine. The blog post was specifically written in response to this type of question – the tool determines whether the machine is considered to be in a "clean" state from an application point of view (by programmatically querying, instead of checking for file presence), indicating there is no need to remove the files if they are present in case of a positive response. Hopefully, this helps the OP and others more than a face-value reply to the question.

Comment: The blog link is now broken, so this answer isn't any use anymore. Could you paste the important text in?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to remove them via (Administrator) Command Line using the rem command.

Comment: Id didn't work. It gave me access denied! and I used the del and rmdir commands

Comment: UGH lol, I don't work on Windows that much. It should be del and rmdir as aF mentioned, you must also run the command line as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove some unneeded things from WinSXS using dism that comes with Windows. In my case, it left one copy of vc90 behind but perhaps others will be luckier:

1. Open Powershell as administrator
2. `dism /online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup`